# Set locale from user function

Tags: yii, locale

I'm trying to just work with adjusting a web page in Yii between languages.

So far I have this simple function tha can be called from the menu bar:

```
    public function actionSetLanguage(){

    if(Yii::app()->language == 'en_us'){

            Yii::app()->language == 'en_uk';
    } else {

            Yii::app()->language == 'en_us';
    }

    $this->redirect(array('site/index'));


}
```

In my index page i'm just printing the value through `Yii::app()->language`.

In my config I have:

```
'language'=>'en_us',
```

My value of `Yii::app()->language` never changes though. It always prints out `'en_us'`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by:

```
    'behaviors' => array('ApplicationConfigBehavior'),
```

in my config:

Followed this article:

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/208/how-to-use-an-application-behavior-to-maintain-runtime-configuration/

Changed it to sessions rather than POST.

Controller updated to

```
    if(Yii::app()->language == 'en_us'){

        Yii::app()->session->add('lang', 'en_uk');
        Yii::app()->language == Yii::app()->session['lang'];
    } else {

            Yii::app()->session->remove('lang');
            Yii::app()->session->add('lang', 'en_us');
            Yii::app()->language == Yii::app()->session['lang'];
    }

    $this->redirect(array('site/index'));
```